# Jquery DataTables with both horizontal and vertical scroll makes browser unresponsive for just 50 records

Tags: datatables, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I'm a great fan of JQuery DataTables and I have used this for very long time. Its the best and working fine. But now with my requirement of enabling both horizontal and vertical scroll, the table makes browser unresponsive for few seconds with just 50 records returned from server. I just have this table script and no other in my page.

Here is the HTML,

```
<div class="page-content">
        <section class="card">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <table id="table" class="table table-sm table-bordered mt-0 w-100">
                    <thead class="text-center"></thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Here is the table script,,

```
var height = dynamically calculated,

table = $('#table').DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                autoWidth: true,
                language: {
                    processing: "Loading...",
                    zeroRecords: "No matching records found"
                },
                processing: true,
                deferRender: true,
                scrollX: true,
                scrollY: height,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                order: [],
                dom: '<tr>',
                ajax: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "server url",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    headers: {
                        "XSRF-TOKEN": $('#_AjaxAntiForgeryTokenForm input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    global: false,
                    async: true,
                    data: function (data) {
                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                  {
                    title:"",
                    data: "",
                    render: function(){
                    },
                    name: ""
                  }
                  //... 19 more columns
                ],
                drawCallback: function (settings) {
                var count = table.data().count();

                $('.data-table-disable').prop('disabled', !(count > 0));
                $('#spanResultsCount').text(count);
                $('section.card').height(height + 27);
            }
});
```

I'm using Jquery Datatables 1.10.18. If I comment the scrollX,scrollY and scrollCollapse properties and run, now horizontal and vertical scroll appears at browser level and there isn't any lag or unresponsiveness.

I followed their docs and found this,
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is it possible `height` is too low? Also do you see additional requests to your server-side script in the Network tab?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com No additional requests to server. And height is not too low. I have even set the height to 70vh but still same issue.

Comment: I have posted this in Jquery DataTables forum and waiting for their response [Jquery DataTable Forum Post Link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/55704/datatables-with-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scroll-makes-browser-unresponsive-for-just-50-records#latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot research and googling I found that adding `paging: false` in the DataTable Initialization fixed the issue. Hope this helps some one. :)